# How does someone debug FinServ Trigger Errors?

Tags: apex, trigger, debugging, financial-services-cloud

Please see below two errors we have been receiving regarding the Financial Lead Trigger and Financial Opportunity Trigger :

**FinServ Lead Trigger :**

```
FinServ.LeadTrigger: execution of BeforeUpdate

caused by: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object

Class.FinServ.MoiBaseTriggerHandler.requireLicenseCheck: line 306, column 1
Class.FinServ.MoiBaseTriggerHandler.handleEvent: line 97, column 1
Trigger.FinServ.LeadTrigger: line 11, column 1
```

**FinServ Opportunity Trigger :**

```
FinServ.OpportunityTrigger: execution of BeforeUpdate

caused by: FinServ.MoiExceptionWrapper.TriggerException: Something's not quite right. Try your action again, and if the issue continues, contact your administrator for help.: sObject type 'AccountContactRelation' is not supported.
```

**How can these triggers be debugged if we don't have access to them?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to contact their support/development team. They will have the tools necessary to debug and/or fix the problem.

Comment: I see, alright thanks!